# Resume an aria2 downloaded file by its *.aria2 file

Tags: download, aria2

I have a partially downloaded file with aria2. Next to it, is a file with the same name end with `.aria2`.
I don't know the download link. I only have these two files. I want to know how could I resume download in this situation.

Note: `*.aria2` is created along side the download file and remains until the download finishes.

Comment: I apologize - my answer only works if you *do* know the url. So I've deleted it. Without it though, I don't think your chances are very good - but hopefully I'm wrong.

Comment: @mikeserv don't do that put it back. just mention that It is for when you have the URL. It is useful stuff

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on the download type, you should use either or both of the following two options:

```
aria2c --continue=true \
    --input-file=${path_to_./aria2_script}
```

But, you will apparently need the url for the download with both options. As far as I can tell, you cannot resume a download without it. I'm sorry this couldn't be better help, but the docs are [here](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-i). These options are described thus:

> `-i`, `--input-file=<FILE>`
>
> Downloads URIs found in FILE. You can specify multiple URIs for a single entity: separate URIs on a single line using the TAB character. Reads input from stdin when - is specified. Additionally, options can be specified after each line of URI. This optional line must start with one or more white spaces and have one option per single line. The input file can use gzip compression. See Input File subsection for details. See also `--deferred-input` option.
>
> `-c`, `--continue[=true|false]`
>
> Continue downloading a partially downloaded file. Use this option to resume a download started by a web browser or another program which downloads files sequentially from the beginning. Currently this option is only applicable to HTTP(S)/FTP downloads.

Comment: I couldn't make it work. if the `*.aria2` is in `~/downloads` how should I precede?

Comment: `2014-07-12 01:05:00.799659 ERROR - Unrecognized URI or unsupported protocol: ���
No files to download.`

Comment: Oh; that is not the answer; it reads a file for example a `.txt` one and look inside for URL(s) to download. we are talking about `*.aria` file; the file which is created along side the download file and remains until the download finishes.

Comment: @r004 - as you requested, I restored the answer. But I don't like it...

Answer (score 4):

If the downloaded file was a torrent you can retrieve it in this way:

```
url=$(echo "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:$(xxd -p -seek 10 -l 20 'FILENAME.aria2')")

aria2c --continue=true $url
```

Comment: `--continue` is only applicable to HTTP(S)/FTP downloads.

Answer (score 2):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
url="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:$(xxd -p -seek 10 -l 20 "$1")"
cd "$(dirname "$1")" || exit 1
shift # Allow further aria2c command line options
exec aria2c "$url" "$@"
```

Credit: @Zibri and https://github.com/aria2/aria2/issues/792

Comment: I almost forgot about this :D